# Confidence interval for variance in fit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

When using (Non)LinearModelFit you can get estimates for all parameters and for the variance of the fit and confidence intervals for parameters, but what about a confidence interval for the variance?

```
Y = vout; (*vin, vout properly defined earlier*)
listn = Table[1, {i, 1, Length[Y]}];
A = Transpose[{listn, vin}]; (*design matrix*)
gammacap = Inverse[Transpose[A] . A] . Transpose[A] . Y 
DF = Length[Y] - Length[gammacap]
vcap = Norm[Y - A . gammacap]^2/DF

a = 0.05; (*level of significance*)
qp = Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[DF], 1 - a/2] 
qm = InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[DF], a/2] 
t = Quantile[StudentTDistribution[DF], 1 - a/2]
da = t Sqrt[
    Transpose[{1, 0}] . Inverse[Transpose[A] . A] . {1, 0}* vcap];
db = t Sqrt[
    Transpose[{0, 1}] . Inverse[Transpose[A] . A] . {0, 1}* vcap];

intconfv = {DF vcap/qp, DF vcap/qm}
intconfa = {gammacap[[1]] - da, gammacap[[1]] + da}
intconfb = {gammacap[[2]] - db, gammacap[[2]] + db}
```

This is what I've been doing (formulas are taken from "Introduction to Probability and Statistics" of Georgii). I'm trying to not blindly use Mathematica's result, instead I wanted to understand the calculations behind those and indeed confidence intervals for parameters coincide with the ones obtained from

```
fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95]
```

Is there an option for the confidence interval of variance (for the moment I'm studying the linear case) ?

Comment: Do you mean the confidence interval for the error variance of the model or for the individual squares of the standard errors of the parameter estimates?

Answer (score 2):

Consider one of the examples in the documentation for `LinearModelFit`:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], 
  1.2 + (3.7 + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]) #[[1]] - 2 #[[2]] 23.4 #[[3]]} &, RandomReal[10, {100, 3}]];
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {x, y, z}, {x, y, z}];

(* Estimate of variance *)
variance = lm["EstimatedVariance"]
(* 12.6157 *)

(* 95% confidence intervals for variance *)
α = 0.05;
dfError = lm["ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom"][[-2]];
{lowerCL, upperCL} = dfError*variance/
  InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[dfError], #] & /@ {1 - α/2, α/2}
(* {9.68888, 17.1102} *)
```